# Flutter: hide and display app bar in scrolling detected

Tags: animation, scroll, flutter, appbar

I'm having trouble with app bar animation, I'm using `SilverAppBar`, in my app. So, the problem is when I'm in the middle of my list and I scroll up, the app bar does not appear, but it appears just when scrolling reaches the top of the items list. I already tested the `snap` parameter and give it `true`, but not the result I expect. I have ideas about creating a custom animation for this, but I'm not too experienced in Flutter, and also if there is a way to add parameters, or another widget that will work for my situation, it would be great.

The actual code of the demo I'm using:

```
  Widget _search() => Container(
        color: Colors.grey[400],
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              enabled: false,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefix: SizedBox(width: 12),
                hintText: "Search",
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 14.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )),
      );

  Container _buildBody() {
    return Container(
        child: new GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: List.generate(100, (index) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            'Item $index',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
          ),
        );
      }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: new NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                new SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text("Demo",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                  pinned: false,
                  floating: true,
                  forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
              _search(),
              new Expanded(child: _buildBody())
            ])));
  }
```

The result I have now:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHIpH.gif)

The result I got after giving `true` to the `snap` parameter:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVjfH.gif)

Plenty of applications like WhatsApp, Facebook, LinkedIn ... have this animating app bar. To explain more what exactly I expect with this animating app bar, I added an example of Google Play Store, showing the wanted animation: [Play Store example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwCTL.gif)

Answer (score 6):

**I had a similar issue with CustomScrollView and SliverAppbar using refresh indicator i ended up creating my own custom appbar.**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

    class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      HomeState createState() => HomeState();
    }

    class HomeState extends State<HomeView> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      bool _isAppbar = true;
      ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            appBarStatus(false);
          }
          if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.forward) {
            appBarStatus(true);
          }
        });
      }

      void appBarStatus(bool status) {
        setState(() {
          _isAppbar = status;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                height: _isAppbar ? 55.0 : 0.0,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                child: CustomAppBar(),
              ),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return container();
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    Widget container() {
      return Container(
        height: 80.0,
        color: Colors.pink,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        width: 100,
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
          'Container',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
          ),
        )),
      );
    }

    class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      AppBarView createState() => new AppBarView();
    }

    class AppBarView extends State<CustomAppBar> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: InkWell(
            onTap: () => {},
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Image.network(
                      'https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/5aee389b3c3a531e6245ae76/1530965251082-9L40PL9QH6PATNQ93LUK/linkedinPortraits_DwayneBrown08.jpg?format=1000w&content-type=image%2Fjpeg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
          title: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text("Custom Appbar", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

To get this functionality to work, you will need to use the `CustomScrollView` widget instead of `NestedScrollView`. [Google Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Here is a working example:

```
class MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        const SliverAppBar(
          pinned: false,
          snap: false,
          floating: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('Demo'),
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            childAspectRatio: 4.0,
          ),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: Text('grid item $index'),
              );
            },
            childCount: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
}
}
```

[Example of this running here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggU1T.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Animation that I want works perfectly, but with this `CustomScrollView`, the search field goes with items list when it reaches the top. I want the search field to be stuck in top when the app bar disappears, like Google Play Store example, or just like my actual example. I edited the code in the question, to add the two functions `_search()` and `_buildBody()`.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to make the floating Appbar with Tabbar similar to that of WhatsApp by using SliverAppbar with NestedScrollView. Do remember to add floatHeaderSlivers: true, in NestedScrollView. [Link to sample code](https://dartpad.dev/0955dcf876ba24619b86d49ec50788cc?)

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: CustomSliverAppbar(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliverAppbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomSliverAppbarState createState() => _CustomSliverAppbarState();
}

class _CustomSliverAppbarState extends State<CustomSliverAppbar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(
                "WhatsApp type sliver appbar",
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                  labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 16,
                  ),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: [
                    Text("TAB A"),
                    Text("TAB B"),
                  ]),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            TabA(),
            const Center(
              child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class TabA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, child) => Divider(
          height: 1,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Link to sample code]

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful and saved the time. floatHeaderSlivers: true is the key here.