# SilverApp hide not working when scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

When we scroll down, we want to hide the `appBar`, only show `tabBar`, which exactly like this [Flutter: hide and display app bar in scrolling detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65405872/5156075)
.

However, it did not work in our case. It will only hide when we click and scroll the `appBar`.

**main.dart**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[TabA(), TabA()],
      ),
      floatHeaderSlivers: true,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("Silver App"),
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
            bottom: TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  text: "Tab A",
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Tab B"),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
    ));
  }
```

**TabA.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class TabA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TabAState();
}

class _TabAState extends State<TabA> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  bool isLoading = false;
  ScrollController _controller;
  int page = 1;
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, 2.0))
        .animate(controller);
  }

  final data = [
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
      ...
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: SlideTransition(
            position: offset,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {})),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
            key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: _refresh,
            child: _showData()));
  }

  void _scrollListener() async {
    if (_controller.position.pixels == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      // display loading on bottom of listView
    }
    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      setState(() {
        controller.forward();
      });
    }
    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      setState(() {
        controller.reverse();
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _showData() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _showListView(),
        // Align(
        //   child: Row(
        //       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        //       children: <Widget>[
        //         Padding(
        //             padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        //             child: Text("loading .....",
        //                 style: TextStyle(
        //                   color: const Color(0xff000066),
        //                   fontSize: 15,
        //                 ))),
        //         SizedBox(
        //           width: 12,
        //         ),
        //       ]),
        //   alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        // )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _showListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(data[index]);
        });
  }

  Future<void> _refresh() {
    // return data;
  }
}
```

Output :

[image: Output]

As you can see, the `appBar` not hiding when `listView` scrolling. It only hide when we press on the `appBar` and scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working code based from your code.

The key point is that 'ScrollController' instance is made by 'NestedScrollView' context
 and pass that 'ScrollController' instance to inside 'ListView' in TabBarView children.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(initialIndex: 0, length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final _scr = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
          return TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[TabA(_scr), TabA(_scr)],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatHeaderSlivers: true,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("Silver App"),
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
            bottom: TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  text: "Tab A",
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Tab B"),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
    ));
  }
}

class TabA extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  TabA(this.scrollController);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TabAState();
}

class _TabAState extends State<TabA> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  bool isLoading = false;
  int page = 1;
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget.scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, 2.0))
        .animate(controller);
  }

  final data = [
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: SlideTransition(
            position: offset,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {})),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
            key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: _refresh,
            child: _showData()));
  }

  void _scrollListener() async {
    if (widget.scrollController.position.pixels ==
        widget.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      // display loading on bottom of listView
    }
    if (widget.scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      setState(() {
        controller.forward();
      });
    }
    if (widget.scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      setState(() {
        controller.reverse();
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _showData() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _showListView(),
        // Align(
        //   child: Row(
        //       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        //       children: <Widget>[
        //         Padding(
        //             padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        //             child: Text("loading .....",
        //                 style: TextStyle(
        //                   color: const Color(0xff000066),
        //                   fontSize: 15,
        //                 ))),
        //         SizedBox(
        //           width: 12,
        //         ),
        //       ]),
        //   alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        // )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _showListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        controller: widget.scrollController,
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(data[index]);
        });
  }

  Future<void> _refresh() {
    // return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error for second tab ```ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views```

Answer (score 1):

try to use same ScrollController for both NestedScrollView & ListView:

```
NestedScrollView(
  controller: _controller,

ListView(
  controller: _controller,
```