# How to make whole screen scrollable include appbar scaffold in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      //   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      // ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Dashboard",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  )),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xff09325E)),
            ),
            Positioned(
                top: 85,
                child: Container(
                  width: 470,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    // height: 500,
                    // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 90,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 100,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                "Kasus Tertinggi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            )),
                        Divider(color: Color(0xffD3D3D3)),
                        Column(children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Text("1",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15)),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 6,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "POLSEK METRO TAMAN SARI",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Pola Waktu 02.00 - 04.00",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Wilayah: KELAGIAN",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          ))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      Text("1",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                      Text("KASUS",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                    ])),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Color(0xffD3D3D3)),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Text("1",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15)),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 6,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "POLSEK METRO TAMAN SARI",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Pola Waktu 02.00 - 04.00",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Wilayah: KELAGIAN",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          ))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      Text("1",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                      Text("KASUS",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                    ])),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Color(0xffD3D3D3)),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Text("1",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15)),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 6,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "POLSEK METRO TAMAN SARI",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Pola Waktu 02.00 - 04.00",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Wilayah: KELAGIAN",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          ))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      Text("1",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                      Text("KASUS",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                    ])),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Color(0xffD3D3D3)),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Text("1",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15)),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 6,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "POLSEK METRO TAMAN SARI",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Pola Waktu 02.00 - 04.00",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          )),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Wilayah: KELAGIAN",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 15),
                                          ))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Column(children: [
                                      Text("1",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                      Text("KASUS",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                    ])),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Color(0xffD3D3D3)),
                        ])
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/create');
        }),
        tooltip: 'Add Product',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/profile');
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have try using singlechild SingleChildScrollView but it's not working, how to make scrollable whole screen include appbar scaffold?

[image]

Comment: Using ``CustomScrollView`` and ``SliverAppBar`` https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/floating-app-bar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: hide and display app bar in scrolling detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054445/flutter-hide-and-display-app-bar-in-scrolling-detected)

Answer (score 1):

Use CustomScrollView, I did some refactoring to your code
import sliver_tools package for sliverStack

```
import 'package:sliver_tools/sliver_tools.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            title: Text(
              'AppBAR',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
            ),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            sliver: SliverStack(
              insetOnOverlap: false,
              children: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xff09325E)),
                    child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Text(
                          "Dashboard",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPositioned.fill(
                  top: 80,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        boxShadow: const [
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(0, 4),
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPositioned.fill(
                  top: 100,
                  child: SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 15, 0),
                    sliver: SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, i) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    const Expanded(
                                      flex: 2,
                                      child: Text("1",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15)),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 6,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: const [
                                          Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                              child: Text(
                                                "POLSEK METRO TAMAN SARI",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 15),
                                              )),
                                          Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Pola Waktu 02.00 - 04.00",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 15),
                                              )),
                                          Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Wilayah: KELAGIAN",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 15),
                                              ))
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        flex: 2,
                                        child: Column(children: const [
                                          Text("1",
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 15)),
                                          Text("KASUS",
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 15)),
                                        ])),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                                child: Divider(color: Color(0xffD3D3D3)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                        childCount: 6,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/create');
        }),
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        tooltip: 'Add Product',
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/profile');
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: great, How can I add a stack widget?

Comment: I edited. for stack U need to install sliver_tools package